# Calculus question with oblique asymptote involved

Tags: calculus

This question is let $$f(x) = \frac{ax^2+bx-c}{x-4}.$$ Determine the values of $a,b,$ and $c$ so that $f(x)$ has an oblique asymptote of $y=3x+1$ and has local minimum at $x=-3$.

I know this requires two equations. The first one requires taking derivative of $f(x)$ and subbing local minimum. But how do I create second equation involving the oblique asymptote.

Comment: What do you know about polynomial division?

Comment: @AndrewChin  I tried using long division by dividing f(x) with the oa but I am confused from that part on.

Comment: is it $ \cdots -\frac{c}{x}-4$ or $ \cdots -\frac{c}{x-4}$?

Comment: @GCab it is the the second one.

Comment: then it is as I amended , right ?

Comment: @GCab Yes thank you for the fix

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\frac{ax^2+bx-c}{x-4}=\overbrace{ax+b+4a}^\text{oblique asymptote}+\overbrace{\frac{16a+4b-c}{x-4}}^{\text{remainder}}$$ and therefore have $a=3$ and $b=-11.$

To calculate $c$, you mentioned that you have to take the derivative and sub in local minimum.  Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: I am confused by the b value difference between your answer and Joshuas.

Comment: You need the constant term of the quotient to be $1$. Thus, we need $b+4a=1$. But $a=3$, so $b+12=1$ which implies $b=-11$

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Im confused about how when I sub a =3, b=-11 and a c point, it does not satisfy the local minimum at x=-3. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6ro7eza8no

Comment: You will need to find the correct value of $c$. You can't just just use any c value

Comment: Since the _remainder_ is the _numerator_ of that fraction, could I suggest changing the two underbraces to overbraces so that the numerator is what that symbols points to?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that, given a $f(x)$ :

- one thing is to find its "asymptotic behaviour" as $x \to \infty$, which means to find a $g(x)$  such that
  $$
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } {{f(x)} \over {g(x)}} = 1
  $$
  and we say that $f$ and $g$ are [asymptotically equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis);
- another thing is to find the function $g(x)$ which is **asymptotically equal** to $f(x)$, i.e. such that
  $$
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \left( {f(x) - g(x)} \right) = 0
  $$

Now,  when we talk to find a horizontal or oblique asymptote to a curve we mean to find a line
which is asyptotic to the curve in the second meaning, i.e. that the distance goes to $0$.

In the first way (*J. Wang*'s answer) you can only determine the slope of the line, but not the intercept because
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } {{f(x)} \over {mx}}
 = 0\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } {{f(x)} \over {mx + q}} = 0
$$

Therefore in your case we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(x) = {{ax^2  + bx - c} \over {x - 4}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{a\left( {x - 4} \right)^2  + b\left( {x - 4} \right) + 8ax - 16a + 4b - c} \over {x - 4}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{a\left( {x - 4} \right)^2  + b\left( {x - 4} \right) + 8a\left( {x - 4} \right) + 16a + 4b - c}
 \over {x - 4}} =   \cr 
  &  = a\left( {x - 4} \right) + b + 8a + {{16a + 4b - c} \over {x - 4}} \cr} 
$$

So for the asymptote we shall have
$$
ax + b + 4a = 3x + 1\quad  \Rightarrow \quad a = 3,\quad b =  - 11
$$
as already indicated by *A.Chin*.

Then the function becomes
$$
f(x) = {{3x^2  - 11x - c} \over {x - 4}} = 3x + 1 - {{c - 4} \over {x - 4}}
$$

It is clear that the function has the required oblique asymptote, as well as a vertical asymptote at $x=4$, where we have:
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 4 + } f(x) = - {\rm sgn}(c - 4) \cdot \infty \quad
 \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 4 - } f(x) =  {\rm sgn}(c - 4) \cdot \infty 
$$
This means that for $c < 4$ you will  have a minimum at $4 < x$ and a maximum at $x < 4$, while
for $4 < c$ you do not have any local extremum.
You can easily check this analytically.

Therefore **a minimum at $x=-3$ is unattainable**.